# Explaining the need to avoid horizontal scroll

Tags: user-interface, scroll, scrollbar

I need help explaining to my boss why her design is poor on a client's website.  She has no knowledge of the web, and it can be difficult as a web developer working with a woman who is a graphic designer (not even a web designer really).  On a current site she has designed, an image bar "needs" to be ~1200px according to her, though it isn't necessary with the content.  A quick sketch to illustrate what's going on:

[image]

As you see, the banner spills out past the 960px of the content and as wide as 1200px.  This creates a horizontal scroll when all the content is viewable within the 960px wide viewport.  I need to make this an <img> and not a CSS background because it's a jQuery slideshow that fades from image to image.

I think this is a big problem because a lot of people are going to get a horizontal scroll bar imposed in their browser when they're still able to see all the relevant content.  She thinks no one will notice and it'll be fine; I think it's very bad practice and confusing to the end user.

**How do I explain the problem to her?**

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but it might be worth working with a "max-width" instead of width. That way you can please your boss and the rest of the world if you're lucky. Changing the background-image can be done via JQuery, so your effect should still be possible. :)

Comment: I know you can change the background image, but fading from background image to background image is not possible in an easy way.

Comment: You can use .fadeIn() / .fadeOut() / .fadeTo() in jQuery. I would say fade to a solid color like white, then to the next image, then to white, then to next image, etc.

Comment: Doesn't your sketch say it all?  Can she not grasp the idea from that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ask her if she would want to open a brochure to only see that one of the folds was unnecessary as it merely has some header image spilling over into it (but no content).

```
XXXXXXX|XXXXXXX
XIMAGEX|XIMAGEX
XXXXXXX|XXXXXXX
       |
Some   | (but
content| this
here   | is 
       | blank)
```

Answer (score 15):

Point her to Nielsen - on of the most famous and top level web usability experts.

"Horizontal Scrolling" is error #3 in "[Top Ten Web-Design Mistakes of 2002](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20021223.html)" article

Also, point out (not sure if Nielsen does) that vast majority of mice don't have **horizontal** scroll wheels (that was a point made in comments of an article discussing Nielsen's article).

Also, do the usual UI thing - TEST!

Pick 5 random people who ideally match the desired user profile. Ask them to use the mock-up with and without warning and observe which one's easier/faster (and ask, but also obseve without asking)

Comment: Don't have horizontal scroll wheels? or do have VERTICAL scroll wheels?

Comment: 2002?  While I love these kinds of studies, 2002 is ancient in internet terms. Surely they have a newer version?

Comment: I don't think human psychology or physiology (which drives vast majority of usability science) changed in 8 years. And technology didn't change either - we still have limited width displays and no-horizontal-scroll mice. The only way this research point will expire is once we will have ubiquitous input devices capable of easy horizontal scroll navigation.

Comment: but now its good as windows 8 did it and new myspace also. Hm how things change!

Comment: @Parhs - I am not quite certain myspace is generally considered to be an shining example of fine web design...

Comment: @DVK Granted, but many, many things that were once considered terrible on the web have been 'learned' by users and are now best practices. Usability changes constantly. Usability years are like dog years -- 10 human years is like 70 usability years.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm.  It sounds like you guys need a requirements analyst to step in the middle here.  Deciding on a broswer specification & resolution that you'll conform to is a fair thing to ask, I think.  Just assuming that 'most' users will have wide screen is not enough for most apps.  Seems like she'd be hard pressed to explain why she can't redesign her banner to be smaller & fit the desired size.

I think that user will absolutely notice the horizontal scroll bar and be annoyed by it.  Because it's not something most users are used to seeing (can't think of any major sites that have one), they'd have (in effect) learn something new to use your site, which is not good.  They should be able to look at a site and be able to use it right away, not spend a few seconds figuring out that the scroll bar doesn't show you any new content, just the additional graphics from the header - those few seconds are where you lose people.

I wonder also, if there's any section 508 guidance on horizontal scroll bars.  That may not matter to you guys, but I'm developing gov't sites, so 508 is a big deal for us day to day.  If you've got a user using just a keyboard or a screen reader, that scroll bar is more than just annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Two points I would make:

1. **NO** major website uses horizontal scroll.  Not one.  This means, regardless of what she considers "good" design, 100% of users will be confused and will probably never see the content off the right side of the screen.
2. Horizontal scroll is the print equivalent of a fold-out or "centerfold" style-page.  Would you make every page in a magazine like this?

Comment: The biggest problem isn't necessarily that they need to scroll to see the content, its that it isn't even content.  The banner just has a face off the the right of the submenu, so its entirely unnecessary to scroll over to see the right portion of someones face that they're not concerned about anyway.

Comment: In that case, point her to the fact that she's wasting vertical space by forcing an unnecessary horizontal scrollbar at the bottom.

Comment: Tried it... She doesn't think that's a problem at all and that I'm just an anal engineer (this is the same woman who gets pissed when I tell her making all the text images so the font can be Futura is absolutely ridiculous).

Comment: @Bradley:  Uh oh... PEBCAK! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_error 
I have the perfect solution: replace your boss :)

Comment: As of 2014, *EVERY* major website uses horizontal scroll.  *EVERY* one.

Answer (score 1):

People read left to right, top to bottom (or right to left in some countries). Because of this they can read a lot more content before they need to start scrolling as they only have to scroll vertically.

If you introduce horizontal scrolling then the user has to potentially scroll at the end of each line rather than at the end of each page.

Answer (score 1):

Almost everybody has a wheel mouse now, but only a very few people have wheel mice that side scroll.  And even fewer people even know wheels can side scroll!

Let her chew on that.

Comment: I don't think mouse scroll wheels are very chewable, although my kids disagreed when they were younger

Answer (score 0):

Try these two points to convince her :

- Show her some data about most used browsers resolutions (still 20% internet users have 1024x768 screen resolution)
- Having some part of the website not visible when the page is loaded is not "user-friendly" (user can miss some critical information)

Comment: The part that is killing me is that there is no information being cut off... All of the actual content is still visible and within the 960px limit, it's just a stupid image that spills off the page.

Comment: I have a widescreen display 1600px wide, yet the browser content window is often right around 800x600.  (I can, and often do, fit four windows---text editor, browser, chat, terminal, feed reader, email, folders, ...---at that resolution and still all of them.)  You can't equate screen resolutions with page resolutions.

Comment: @rogerpate

I agree with you 100%.  She's "positive" about 2 things.  Most of our users will have widescreen monitors like us (even though I showed her contrary evidence).  Secondly, no average user will ever even notice a horizontal scroll bar, so the fact that it scrolls to reveal no content is not a problem... I obviously am losing this battle -- If you enter into an argument with a fool, you've already lost.

Answer (score 0):

You should give her examples and show her what she is trying to do. Do you really want to scroll horizontally to get to information on the other side of the page.

http://www.badwebsiteideas.com/horizontal.htm

Answer (score 0):

Can the entire banner and all the component images within it be scaled down to be narrower? (admittedly it woudl also be shorter, may be more difficult to read etc). Then if the face on the right is really important it woudl still be visible... Horizontal scroll is just really really bad. But I guess you (and everyone else) already knew that :)

Comment: I could scale it down, but we need the face to be pushed far enough away that the submenu that floats in there is over plain white and isn't obscured by the face.

Comment: Can the main content area be narrower to accommodate it? But then again, you're now talking about scaling down the entire webpage. You're swimming against the tide here, I feel your pain :)