# Grid View Format By Row

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm wondering if it is possible to format a Grid View like the pattern below

```
Usual Grid View:

Name     Address     Age     Gender  <---  Fields Name
Example  Example     Example Example <---  Values


What I want to look like

"Fields"      "Values"
Name          Example
Address       Example
Age           Example
Gender        Example
```

Any thought will be highly appreciated

Comment: I'm still searching because I'm totally got no ideas.  =(

Comment: Do you need to show single record in this table?

Comment: Yes. in case of adding records by row, I want to add records by column

Comment: Then you use a DetailsView control instead

Comment: is there no way to format a GV like that?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: thanks I didn't know that was not able.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an Answer using this Codes:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  >

<Columns>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
<ItemTemplate>

Name: <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label><br />

Address: <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Address") %>'></asp:Label><br />

Postcode: <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Postcode") %>'></asp:Label><br />

</ItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should look into using a [repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163780.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I think that `GridView` was simply not meant to be used that way. Usually, you will display several items in it and if those items are too many you will end up with the [horizontal scrolling mistake](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/top-ten-web-design-mistakes-of-2002/) (also, some nice arguments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2501930/674700)).

If you are showing only one record, you should use a [`DetailsView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.aspx) control, which:

> Displays the values of a single record from a data source in a table,
>   where each data row represents a field of the record. The DetailsView
>   control allows you to edit, delete, and insert records.