# Expanding more cols to fit width of less cols in Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, layout

In the [output](http://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/mznLqdw4/embedded/result/#Result) of [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/mznLqdw4/):

```css
.row div {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <h1>col-sm-3</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <h1>col-sm-3</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <h1>col-sm-3</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <h1>col-sm-3</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <h1>col-sm-2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <h1>col-sm-2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <h1>col-sm-2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <h1>col-sm-2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <h1>col-sm-2</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and for some reason, I needed to **expand 5 `.col-sm-2` columns to fit width of 4 `.col-sm-3` columns**.

I know that each `.row` can accommodate maximum 12 `.cols-sm-*` (i.e the sum of * is 12).

- If I expand the 2nd row by setting the [style attribute `width`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp), it adds an overflow

> What is the most *safest* way to achieve this without [horizontal scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2501908/2404470)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite rule, but not globally, for example, wrap your row into custom class (custom-row in my demo) and set col-sm-2 minimum width to 20%. See demo.

You should put all rows in container.

http://jsfiddle.net/mznLqdw4/2/

```css
.row div {
  border: 1px solid;
}
.custom-row .col-sm-2 {
  min-width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <h1>col-sm-3</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <h1>col-sm-3</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <h1>col-sm-3</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <h1>col-sm-3</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="custom-row">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <h1>col-sm-2</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <h1>col-sm-2</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <h1>col-sm-2</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <h1>col-sm-2</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <h1>col-sm-2</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want 100% width, you can change `<div class="container"></div>` to `<div class="container-fluid"></div>`

Comment: There is white space on the [right side](http://jsfiddle.net/mznLqdw4/2/embedded/#Result) :( and I'm not using `.container` also

Comment: Ok. You can overwrite rule, but not globally, for example, wrap your row into custom class (`custom-row` in my demo) and set `col-sm-2` minimum width to 20%. [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mznLqdw4/4/embedded/#Result).

Comment: Yes, global overriding is dangerous. I'm accepting this as answer

Answer (score 2):

overwrite style as below by adding a class to it so that it  doesn't overwrite the general behavior at other palces

```
.col-sm-2 {
width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: It works like a charm. Can I give one more +1 please? Also, I believe it should work consistently across browsers. Thank you!!

Comment: Yes, it's correct, but don't overwrite bootstrap rules globally. See comment to my answer.